# What do angle brackets nearby extensible class mean in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax

For what are using angle brackets `<>` in class inheritance declaration in Dart language?

Code example from Flutter's project code:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
...
}
```

The code tells that class `_HomeState` extends class `State`, but for what is `<Home>`?

Answer (score 2):

Official docs says that `State<T extends StatefulWidget>` class
is **The logic and internal state for a StatefulWidget**.

so in your case we will have:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Official documentation:
[State Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html)
[StatefulWidget Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

The angle brackets indicates a **Generic type** in Dart, in this case meaning class `Home` has to extend (derive from, or is a child class of) the `StatefulWidget` class.

https://dart.dev/language/generics